# zend-framework, call an action helper from within another action helper

Tags: zend-framework

i am writing an action helper and i need to call another action helper from within that helper. but i dont know how. here in the sample code:

```
class Common_Controller_Action_Helper_SAMPLE extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    protected $_view;
    public function __construct(Zend_View_Interface $view = null, array $options = array())
    {
        $this->_view = $view;
    }

    public function preDispatch()
    {
        $flashMessenger = $this->_helper->FlashMessenger; // IT IS NULL
    }
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the [action helper broker](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.broker):

```
$flashMessenger =
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessenger');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use getActionController to get a reference back to the actioncontroller you were using for any methods you'd normally use there.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to mercator's answer, add your method after, see example below:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessenger')->myMethod();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call it in this way:

```
$this->_actionController->OtherActionHelper();
```

The `_actionController` property references the actual action controller.

Comment: When attempting to use this answer, I got a `Undefined property` on my controller. The accepted answer did however work for me.