# Zend Framework - How to call controller's redirect() from within an action helper

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am doing an ACL check in the preDispatch method of an Action Helper.  When it fails, I want to call the action controller's _redirect method however I am having difficulty doing this.

In the comments attached to this post, [zend-framework, call an action helper from within another action helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116401/zend-framework-call-an-action-helper-from-within-another-action-helper), I see two solutions.  In the first, the controller is accessed from the helper as $this->_actionController.  In the second, it is accessed using $this->getActionController().

I tried both of the following:

```
$this->_actionController->_redirect('/');
$this->getActionController()->_redirect('/');
```

In either case I get 'Method "_redirect" does not exist ...'.  Are there perhaps restrictions on which controller methods can be accessed from the action helper?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is [Redirector action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.redirector) that you could use in your action helpers. For example:

```
class My_Controller_Action_Helper_Test extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract {

     public function preDispatch()  {
        $redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Redirector');         
        $redirector->gotoUrl('/url');
    }            
}
```

Controller's [_redirect method](https://github.com/mridgway/Zend-Framework-1.x-Mirror/blob/master/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php#L689) is just a wrapper to the Redirector's `gotoUrl` method.

Answer (score 0):

example how to do it in preDispatch():

```
$request = $this->getActionController()->getRequest();
$urlOptions = array('controller' => 'auth', 
                    'action' => 'login');
$redirector = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector();
$redirector->gotoRouteAndExit($urlOptions, null, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use :

```
$this->_response->setRedirect('/login');
$this->_response->sendResponse();
```

Or :

```
$this->_request->setModuleName('default');
$this->_request->setControllerName('error');
$this->_request->setActionName('404');
```